# XML-drawable don't work correctly using layer-list

Tags: android, xml

When i work with XML-drawable file using layer-list it does not appear in **Preview** and does not work as a background for the elements (in particular **Spinner**).

*Drawable-XML listing:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f3f4f6"></solid>
            <size android:width="500px" android:height="100px"></size>
            <corners android:radius="35px"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/down-arrow" android:gravity="center|right"></bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How to fix? Regards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is probably easier than you think:

You can't use "-" as a file resource name. File resource names should contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9 or underscore.

Just rename your `@drawable/down-arrow` resource to `@drawable/down_arrow` (rename source image file)